# 'failed to create query: field [vector] does not exist in the mapping'

Tags: python, pandas, elasticsearch

I am creating a project on querying data through elastic search
This is the error I'm getting

```
BadRequestError: BadRequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'failed to create query: field [vector] does not exist in the mapping')
```

and here is the code

```
class ElasticSearchImports(object):
    def __init__(self, df, index_name='posting'):
        self.df = df
        self.index_name = index_name
        self.es = Elasticsearch(timeout=600,hosts=os.getenv(ENDPOINT),cloud_id=F,http_auth=("elastic", P))
        
  


    def run(self):

        elk_data = self.df.to_dict("records")

        for job in elk_data:
            try:self.es.index(index=self.index_name,body=job)
            except Exception as e:pass

        return True
helper = Reader(file_name="data job posts.csv")
df = helper.run();
tqdm.pandas()
helper_token = Tokenizer()
df["vectors"] = df["jobpost"].progress_apply(helper_token.get_token) 
helper_elk = ElasticSearchImports(df=df) 
helper_elk.run()
INPUT = input("Enter the Input Query: ")
token_vector = helper_token.get_token(INPUT)
print(token_vector)
es = Elasticsearch(timeout=600,hosts=os.getenv(ENDPOINT),cloud_id=CLOUDID,http_auth=("elastic", PASSWORD))
res = es.knn_search(index = 'posting', source = [ "title", "job_description" ],
          knn = {
          "field": "vector",
          "k": 5,
          "num_candidates": 10,
          "query_vector": token_vector
  })
title = [x['_source']  for x in res['hits']['hits']] 

for item in title:
      print(item)
```

Please help me with this, tried to search about it on stackoverflow but the solutions didn't work.

Comment: Error: field [vector] does not exist in the mapping. Show your mapping.

Comment: did you defined field called `vectors` as vector type in elasticsearch ? it seems like you are going with default mapping and that is the reason why it is throwing this error.